# puppeteer taking screenshot of element children one by one

Tags: javascript, async-await, puppeteer

I'm trying to get a screenshot of a webpage with puppeteer, I want to take a screenshot of each elements one by one by **revealing them 1 after another** with the following type of data:

```
p (visibility:hidden)
ol
 li (visibility:hidden)
 li (visibility:hidden)
```

In that case, I'll change p to visible, take a screenshot, go in the ol, set li to visible, take a screenshot, and so on.

I'm almost able to make it work with the following function :

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--window-size=1920,1080','--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://mywebsite',{waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    const div = await page.$("[id^=t1_]");
    const bbox = await div.boundingBox();


    let nbElem=await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('[class$=-root]').childElementCount
    });

    for(let i=1;i<=nbElem;i++){
        await page.evaluate((i) => {
            let elem = document.querySelector('[class$=-root] > *:nth-child('+i+')')
            if(elem.tagName==="P"){
                elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
                div.screenshot({path: "test"+i+"0.png",clip: {x: bbox.x,y:bbox.y,width: bbox.width,height: bbox.height}})
            }else{
                let j=0;
                let children = elem.children;
                for(let z of children){
                    z.style.visibility='visible';
                    div.screenshot({path: "test"+i+(j++)+".png",clip: {x: bbox.x,y:bbox.y,width: bbox.width,height: bbox.height}})
                }
            }
        },i);
//        await div.screenshot({path: "test"+i+(j++)+".png",clip: {x: bbox.x,y:bbox.y,width: Math.min(bbox.width, page.viewport().width),height: Math.min(bbox.height, page.viewport().height),}})
    }
```

Once in the **await page.evaluate**, I can't call **div.screenshot**, I get the following error :

`(node:26413) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: div.screenshot is not a function`

I did try to call it with the **await**, but get another error :

```
await div.screenshot({path: "test"+i+"0.png",clip: {x: bbox.x,y:bbox.y,width: bbox.width,height: bbox.height}})
                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

while after **page.evaluate**, I can, but in that case, I'm missing the "unveiling" of each li.

I definitely don't know what I'm doing with the await and async stuff in that case ...

I don't understand how I could transform the anonymous function into a async one to fit inside the page.evaluate.

How should I call div.screenshot within page.evaluate ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't call screenshot inside the evaluate function

Comment: I still don't understand this part: `const div = await page.$("[id^=t1_]")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you were confused with the `page.evaluate` really means. The `page.evaluate` method is the puppeteer function to run script INSIDE the Chromium puppeteer's browser, not in puppeteer itself. Both were different contexts and have it's own environment, and you can't share variables or constants.

And you can't call div.screenshot within `page.evaluate`

I tried to make some HTML to reproduce your case, `coba.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="body-root">
    <p style="visibility:hidden">Hallo</p>
    <p style="visibility:hidden">World</p>
    <p style="visibility:hidden">How Are You?</p>
    <ol>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">1</li>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">3</li>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">5</li>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">7</li>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">9</li>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">A</li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">2</li>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">4</li>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">6</li>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">8</li>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">10</li>
        <li style="visibility:hidden">B</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

And here you go.

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer')

;(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        devtools: true,
        args: [
            '--window-size=1920,1080',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox'
        ]
    })

    const [page] = await browser.pages ()

    await page.goto('http://localhost/testing/coba.html',{ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })

    await page.evaluate ( () => {

        document.querySelector('[class$="-root"]').childNodes.forEach( element => {
            if (typeof (element.tagName) !== 'undefined'){

                if (element.tagName === 'P') {
                    element.style.visibility = 'visible'
                } else {
                    element.childNodes.forEach( elemChild => {
                        if (typeof (elemChild.tagName) !== 'undefined'){
                            elemChild.style.visibility = 'visible'
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })

    })


    const pElements = await page.$$('[class$="-root"] > p')
    for ( let num = 0; num < pElements.length; num++ ) {

        var pElementBoundingBox = await pElements[num].boundingBox ()
        pElements[num].screenshot ({ path: `p_elem_${num+1}.png`, clip: pElementBoundingBox })

    }

    const olElements = await page.$$('[class$="-root"] > ol')
    for ( let numol = 0; numol < olElements.length; numol++ ) {

        var liElements = await olElements[numol].$$('li')
        for ( let numli = 0; numli < liElements.length; numli++ ) {

            var liElementBoundingBox = await liElements[numli].boundingBox ()
            liElements[numli].screenshot ({ path: `li_elem_${numol+1}_${numli+1}.png`, clip: liElementBoundingBox })

        }
    }

})()
```

Comment: My pleasure :) .